# Passing Multiple parameters to Web Method using jQuery in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webmethod

i have bind drop down using WebMethod (Services)
I have multiple drop down list and need to bind on mutully dependent to each other like cascading of dropdown list but while passing value for one selected vale its showing null while debugging on my web method

WebMethod:

```
 public static List<Company> GetCompanies(string CountryCode, string CompanyCode)
        {
            GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient oClient = new GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient();
            Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COMPANY_M[] initiatorsList = oClient.GetActiveCompanies(CountryCode, CompanyCode)                                                                                 List<Company> Companyes = new List<Company>();
            foreach (Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COMPANY_M company in initiatorsList)
            {
                Companyes.Add(new Company()
                {
                    CountryCode = company.CompanyCode,
                    CompanyName = company.CompanyName
                });
            }
            return Companyes;
        }
```

JQuery

```
 $('#ddlCountry').change(function (e) {

   var selectedCountry = $('#ddlCountry').val();
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Header.aspx/GetCompanies",
            data: JSON.stringify({ CountryCode: selectedCountry, CompanyCode: 'SAU' }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (res) {
            $.each(res.d, function (data, value) {
            $("#ddlCompany").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CompanyId).html(value.CompanyName));

            $('#ddlCompany').change(function (e) {
```

Aspx:

```
 <div class="col-md-8">
       <select id="ddlCountry">
          <option value="0">--Select Country--</option>
       </select>
 </div>
```

[image]
Where i am doing wrong Please guide me

Comment: In the web browser, use F12 tools and network tab to work out what the ajax is posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the currently selected value from dropdown:

```
$('#ddlCountry').val();
```

To get the currently selected text from dropdown:

```
$('#ddlCountry :selected').text();
```

You can check first  your ajax call is working properly or not , by sending hard coded text by specifying like this in ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Header.aspx/GetCompanies",
    data: JSON.stringify({ CountryCode: 'USA', CompanyCode: 'SAU' })
    ....
```

Then you can check are you assign dropdown values properly or not ? If you only want text not value then you can use as I have mentioned on top. I think it will solve your problem. Please let me know if it isn't.

============ Updated (after reading comments) ======================

I have created a sample demo based on your sample. As I don't have the service code as you have so it is very simple to give it a test to check either it is working or not or it will give me the same error as like yours.

What I have done for testing this may be look trivial to you but please check , it works for me and give me right result. here is screen shot of Route Config file , take a look at the red circle ( I have to change this for web method works)

[image: RouteConfig file image]

Screen shot of chrome dev tools ( for Contact.aspx page here for simplicity)
[image: Chrome dev tools screen shot]

And finally Contact.aspx -> GetCompanies web method break point hit screen shot , here i have modified method body for simplicity , just to check data binding is working or not.

[image]

So , it's work for me. Would you please check all of your step one by one and let me know. If it will help you then it will be my pleasure.

Comment: Hard coded value is working but $('#ddlCountry').val(); is not working

Comment: Iam binding these drop down list using services

Comment: Then would you check your services value in debugger , are those okay or not ?

Comment: I checked its coming even though i have bind 1st drop down list successfully i want those values which already bind from 1st drop down list

Comment: @user14304386 I have re-edited my answer , please check and let me know.

Comment: I am working on WebForm so i don't have Route Config file. Rather then that every thing is same as you suggested Should i add WebMethod in my CODE? Please help me sir

Comment: @user14304386 Could you share your code part in github,bitbucket or dropbox or any other platform , not all the project just your code portion ? I will give it a try. Basicaly problem could be in any part.

Comment: Thanks A Lot sir its working now thanks for your valuable time

Comment: @user14304386 Then you can answer in this post to show other how you have solved this, If you can't post an answer for your rating point you could comment here also to broadcast other people how you solve your problem , because at the end of the day stack overflow moto is to help people or give knowledge people about problem solution. Have a good day.

Comment: I have posted my Ans Please check I was doing silly mistake in that thanks for your help

Comment: @user14304386 Thanks for your re-post. If you think I helps you , you can give me an upvote if you like. Happy coding.

Comment: Done sir you really help me a lot I have also accepted your answerer

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to stringify it.

Instead of:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ CountryCode: selectedCountry, CompanyCode: 'SAU' }),
```

try:

```
data: { CountryCode: selectedCountry, CompanyCode: 'SAU' },
```

Comment: Added but not its not firing web method

Answer (score 0):

Do you need .aspx suffix?

```
Try like this url: "Header/GetCompanies",
```

Answer (score 0):

Very silly point I miss out here From web Method I Was returning `CompanyCode` as you can see

CountryCode = company.CompanyCode,
CompanyName = company.CompanyName

And In Html I was trying to bind `CompanyId` as you can see here :

```
$("#ddlCompany").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CompanyId).html(value.CompanyName));
```

So it was coming null or 0 for obvious region.

I Just replace `value.CompanyId` to `CompanyCode` and its now working perfectly